# Spark: Expansion of RDD(Key, List) to RDD(Key, Value)

Tags: apache-spark, key-value, rdd

So I have an RDD of something like this

```
RDD[(Int, List)]]
```

Where a single element in the RDD looks like

```
(1, List(1, 2, 3))
```

My question is how can I expand the key value pair to something like this

```
(1,1)
(1,2)
(1,3)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`rdd.flatMap { case (key, values) => values.map((key, _)) }`

Answer (score 4):

And in Python (based on @seanowen's answer):

```
rdd.flatMap(lambda x: map(lambda e: (x[0], e), x[1]))
```

Comment: thanks for the python port :) did you mean rdd.flatMap(lambda x: map(lambda e: (x[0], e), x[1])) - can you please check?

Comment: Not involved in this project anymore so unfortunately cannot check, but if the answer is incorrect and you can verify the reverse order is the right one, pls feel free to edit.