# Explanation of lambda function inside flatMap function: rdd.flatMap(lambda x: map(lambda e: (x[0], e), x[1]))?

Tags: python, apache-spark, lambda, pyspark

I had the exact same question as the question found at this link: [Spark: Expansion of RDD(Key, List) to RDD(Key, Value)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36392938/spark-expansion-of-rddkey-list-to-rddkey-value) and the answer did turn out to be correct.

The question was to turn an RDD such as:

```
(1, List(1, 2, 3))
```

into

```
(1,1)
(1,2)
(1,3)
```

However, I would really like to understand what the lambda functions are doing so that I'm not just blindly copying and pasting. Could anyone please explain how this is working?

Comment: just curious, what import is the capital List. it's undefined for me when i try to create an object.

Comment: I mean this is not real code, it's just there to explain the concept of what the original poster was trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `rdd.flatMap(lambda x: map(lambda e: (x[0], e), x[1]))` the function:

```
 map(lambda e: (x[0], e), x[1])
```

is the same as the following list comprehension:

```
[ (x[0], e) for e in x[1] ]
```

which, for the example data, yields a list of tuples (1, 1), (1, 2) and (1, 3), you then take flatMap to convert each item onto their own RDD elements.

For this particular question, it's simpler to just use [flatMapValues](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD.flatMapValues):

```
rdd.flatMapValues(lambda x:x).collect()
#[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3)]
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, it makes a lot more sense. Also, I did not know that flatMapValues was a thing, that's a much simpler way to do it! I'll definitely switch over to using that in my implementation.